# Subversion over https + WebDAV on nginx

Tags: svn, webdav, nginx

I wonder how do I create `SVN repo` and let users access it over `http[s]` + `WebDAV` on `nginx`

I did not find any good tutorials describing this process whilst there are a lot of answers on this scheme but using `apache` instead of `nginx`, so, probably if there is an answer, it may be added to the `community wiki` or I just was searching badly.

*UPDATE*:
[Igor Sysoev answered this question](http://nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2009-February/009628.html), actually, but it's old a "little" bit.
Maybe, something has changed and somebody found a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The question is actually about mod_subversion, which is part of subversion and is written only for apache. One should rewrite whole module, ditch threads, profile data processing so that any other workers wouldn't starve. As nginx isn't posed as application server like apache I doubt there would be any support.